# Adding text after custom_excerpt_length function

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add some text after limiting the excerpt in Wordpress with the function:

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
return 30;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

Code reference [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/excerpt_length/)

I guess I can add some code after the "return 30" but I don't know how to do it.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Only one specific place, or everywhere where excerpt is used?

Comment: This might help: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/37659/143208 using ``add_filter('wp_trim_excerpt', callback )``

Comment: @Frizzant everywhere the excerpt is used